# ggplot color time series region by state

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series that goes like this:

```
   state value frame
1:     1 40070     2
2:     2 53865     3
3:     2 44142     4
4:     1 45004     5
5:     2 41057     6
6:     2 54570     7
```

For each frame there's a value, and a state determined by a Hidden Markov Model. I want to color each region of the graph by the state it's in.  E.g. like so: [image]

However, all the topics I find seem to draw one or two rectangles manually.

Comment: Check out Exercise 1 for an example of how to color the background of a plot based on data values: http://jcyhong.github.io/ggplot_demo.html

Comment: The data set in the tutorial has start and end dates in the data for each period though, which makes it much easier. I only have a random mixture of 1, 2 and 3 for my states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can and want to use `ggplot2`, we can do something along these lines:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(text = '   state value frame
1:     1 40070     2
                 2:     2 53865     3
                 3:     2 44142     4
                 4:     1 45004     5
                 5:     2 41057     6
                 6:     2 54570     7', header = T)
ggplot(df) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = frame, xmax = dplyr::lead(frame), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = factor(state)), 
              alpha = .4) +
    geom_line(aes(x = frame, y = value)) +
    theme_minimal()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

[image]

Comment: That's absolutely beautiful, and way simpler than I thought.